# DeviceMotionEvent Request Permission with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Implementing a gyroscope permission request, but i get a typescript error on requestPermission

My code:

```
if (typeof (DeviceMotionEvent) !== 'undefined' && typeof (DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission) === 'function') {
        return DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
            .then((response: string) => response === 'granted');
}
```

```
TS2339: Property 'requestPermission' does not exist on type '{ new (type: string, eventInitDict?: 
DeviceMotionEventInit): DeviceMotionEvent; prototype: DeviceMotionEvent; }'.
```

Struggling a bit with this one. i tried casting request permission like this (DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() as any) but it stays the same. Since it's not a module i cannot just do yarn add @types/...

Answer (score 7):

Please try to avoid casting types to `any`, since its bad and instead try to narrow the type.

Extend native Web API [`DeviceOrientationEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent) event for iOS devices:

```
interface DeviceOrientationEventiOS extends DeviceOrientationEvent {
  requestPermission?: () => Promise<'granted' | 'denied'>;
}

const requestPermission = (DeviceOrientationEvent as unknown as DeviceOrientationEventiOS).requestPermission;
const iOS = typeof requestPermission === 'function';
if (iOS) {
    const response = await requestPermission();
    if (response === 'granted') {
      // execute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the Object, not the function, try this:

```
(DeviceMotionEvent as any).requestPermission()
```